# How to embed unmanaged dll into console app

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, embedded-resource

Hi guys, I read lot articles about this question but nothing that I tried worked.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Reflection;
using xNet.Net;
using xNet.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool CloseClipboard();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool SetClipboardData(uint uFormat, IntPtr data);


        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            go();
        }

        public static void go()
        {
            CookieDictionary cookies = new CookieDictionary();
            Console.WriteLine(@"[~] Trying to upload text to http://pastebin.ru/");
            try
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequest())
                {
                    request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
                    request.EnableEncodingContent = true;
                    request.Cookies = cookies;
                    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

                    var postData = new RequestParams();
                    postData["parent_pid"] = "";
                    postData["std-x"] = "1440";
                    postData["std-y"] = "900";
                    postData["poster"] = "";
                    postData["code_name"] = "";
                    postData["code"] = @"text";
                    postData["mode"] = "178";
                    postData["private"] = "1";
                    postData["expired"] = "1";
                    postData["paste"] = "Отправить";

                    var response = request.Post("http://pastebin.ru/", postData);
                    var url = response.Location;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(@"[!] Failed to upload text to http://pastebin.ru/\r\n");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        url = @"http://pastebin.ru" + url;
                        Console.WriteLine(@"[+] Successfully uploaded to " + url);
                        OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero);
                        var ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(url);
                        SetClipboardData(13, ptr);
                        CloseClipboard();
                        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NetException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Net error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried to add reference to dll, add it to project, changed Build Action to embedded resource, but nothing worked. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by Embedding unmanaged dll? Espacially embedding `user32.dll`? Having it included in the exe file?

Comment: You want to embed xNet.dll as a binary resource in your executable? Or are you trying to call functions that are in xNet.dll? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: @ I trying to call functions that are in xNet.dll

Comment: Then you'll have to show us those function prototypes and we can help you create the managed prototypes that allow you to call them from your C# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the assembly of your project `MyAssembly`.

Create a new folder at the root of your project in Visual Studio. Let's call it `MyDlls`.

Put your assembly you want to include in this folder and set their *Build Action* to *Embedded Resource*.

Then, in your code, add the following elements:

```
class Program
{
    // ... Your code

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;  // Called when the assembly hasn't been successfully resolved

        // ... Your code
    }

    private Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];  // Gets the assembly name to resolve.

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyAssembly.MyDlls." + assemblyName + ".dll"))  // Gets the assembly in the embedded resources
        {
            if (stream == null)
                return null;

            byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length); 
            return Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
        }
    }
}
```